# How do I write an id to a file and then read it back?

Tags: c++

So I need to have a static number which counts the number of objects and then this is assigned to the id. Then I need to have this id unique so it can never be used again, even when I close the application and open it again. How do I do that?

piggyBank.cpp

```
int PiggyBank::nrOfObjects = 0; // outside constructor

PiggyBank::getNrOfObjects(){

return nrOfObjects;

}

PiggyBank::PiggyBank(void){
  {this->owner="";this->balance=0;this->broken=false;}
  id = ++nrOfObjects;
}

PiggyBank::PiggyBank(std::string name){
  { this->owner=name;this->balance=0;this->broken=false; }
  id = ++nrOfObjects;
}

PiggyBank::PiggyBank(std::string name, int startBalance){
    {this->owner=name;this->balance=startBalance;this->broken=false;}
    id = ++nrOfObjects;
   }
```

piggyBank.h

```
private:
    std::string owner; // PiggyBank owner
    int balance; // Current balance in PiggyBank
    bool broken; // true if PiggyBank is broken, else false
    int id;
    static int nrOfObjects;
public:
    PiggyBank(void);

    PiggyBank(std::string name);

    PiggyBank(std::string name, int startBalance);

    static int getNrOfObjects();
```

Comment: Every C++ tutorial covers the use of files at some point. For advanced reading, research what "serialization" means and also the rationale for using a database.

Comment: @Fiphe did the answer answer your question? if so, consider closing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fstream` to write to a file, and `ifstream` to read from it.
For example:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
```

In order to write to a file:

```
fstream out_file {filename,ios::out | ios::binary);}; //create file
out_file.write((char*)&pointerToObject, sizeof(obj)); //write data to file
out_file.close();                                     //close the file
```

In order to read from a file:

```
ifstream ifile;                                       
ifile.open(filename, ios::in | ios::binary);          //open file
ifile.seekg (0, ifile.end);
ifile length = ifile.tellg();                         //get file length
ifile.seekg (0, ifile.beg);
char * buffer = new char [length];                    //create buffer
ifile.read(buffer,length);                            //read from file to buffer
ifile.close();                                        //close file
delete[] buffer;
```